# Yii 2 object Error

Tags: yii, yii2

[image: Image 1]

[image: imgae 2]

Please help me , i'm basic Yii 2. when I try to provide product information, I got "Trying to get property of non-object".
Thank you very much

Comment: You didn't checked if model is found. Add `if($model)` after `findOne()` in your action.

Comment: You use `products` in view but `product` in controller.

Comment: Just take a look at the method findModel of any autogenerated controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$product` is null, you need to check if $product is null in `actionView`,

```
public function actionView($id){
//Your Query
if(!$product)
  throw new NotFoundHttpException('The Post is not exist.');
// $this-render … 
}
```